# How to compare elements of a list using streams?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, foreach, java-stream

For example, I need to iterate through custom list `List<Model>` and compare items in it. So with `for` loop it would look like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size()-1; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
        if (list.get(i).getSomeItem().equals(list.get(j).getSomeItem()){
                /*modify the list using*/
                list.get(j).setSomeOtherItem(list.get(i).getSomeItem()+list.get(j).getSomeItem());
        }
    }
}
```

But how to get same result with streams or `forEach()` ? I'm trying to make something like this

```
for (Model i : list){
    for (Model j : list){
        if(i.getSomeItem.equals(j.getSomeItem()){
            /*same logic as in for loop*/
        }
    }
}
```

or this

```
 List<StorageModel> newList = list.stream()
           .filter(item -> item.getSomeItem.equals...)
```

So the problem is that with `forEach` both loops starts from the same element and compare the same items. With streams I don't event know how to get next value. Is the any way to do this ?

Comment: It really matters what that *"some logic"* is, to implement it via streams. Otherwise, you are better off with the for each iteration anyway.

Comment: Ok, my bad! I will remove it.

Comment: Why do you want to replace that working code using traditional for-loop with something using streams? Only because you are using Java8 or above doesn't mean everything should be rewritten.

Comment: @Eritrean I'm trying to learn new things and I thought this problem would be interesting :)

Comment: do you want to compare `i` with `i+1` element or `i` with rest of the elements in the list ? @SauliusMeidus

Comment: If you want to learn about streams using this example, then try grouping the same elements by whatever criteria you have, and afterwards you apply the logic to each group.

Comment: both loops are not does this same. First loop doesn't set the first occurrences, second checks and changes all accurrences. For example input {1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4} in first loop i have output: {0,0,0,0,2,4,6,8}, on second loop: {2,4,6,8,2,4,6,8}

Answer (score 1):

It is very important to understand that the streaming api provided by Java is not just an API, but a different programming paradigm as well. When you use streams you need to embrace the paradigm. **You tell streams what you want to achieve, but not how you want to achieve it**. And, as with many other things, using streams is not always the best solution. Sometimes, using plain old foor loops makes the code easier to read and probably perform better, too.

### Using Streams

If you want to use streams in this example, you could do something similar as below.

As far as I can tell, you are trying to find elements that (based on some criteria) are the same. In other words, you want to group elements based on the value of a property of the `Model` object.

Let's say our `Model` class looks like this:

```
public class Model {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Model(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

The example below shows how to group elements of a list of models based on their names.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class CompareItems {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Model> items = Arrays.asList(
                new Model(1, "model_1"), new Model(2, "model_2"), new Model(3, "model_1"),
                new Model(4, "model_3"), new Model(5, "model_2"), new Model(6, "model_2"));

        Map<String, Set<Integer>> result = 
                items.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Model::getName, Collectors.mapping(Model::getId, Collectors.toSet())));

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

When you print the `result` object, you will get this:

```
{model_1=[1, 3], model_3=[4], model_2=[2, 5, 6]}
```

In the `result` object you have the name of a model and ID-s of all model objects that have the same name.

Depending on what you want to do, you can then apply the changes to each group by iterating over the `result` object.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two ArrayLists A and B, you can get

- A + B with A.addAll(B)
- A - B with A.removeAll(B)
- A ∩ B with A.retainAll(B)
- A ∪ B with copying A to Set A' then A'.addAll(B)

Then you can use streams to process the result if you need to. However getting the desired subset you are interested in (for example items in common or A ∩ B) is really not something I would consider doing with streams.

Answer (score 0):

You can try reduce method in this cases.

```
list.stream().reduce((Item a, Item b)->{
        if(a.equals(b)){
            a.setValue(a.getValue()+b.getValue());
        }
        return b;
    });
```